# Phalcon Devtools 1.2.3: "WebtoolsController handler class cannot be loaded"

Tags: php, command-line-interface, phalcon, devtools

I input this:

```
$ phalcon create-project store --enable-webtools
```

I get a:

```
Phalcon DevTools (1.2.3)


  Success: Controller "index" was successfully created.


  Success: Project "store" was successfully created.
```

and then when i access: `http://localhost/store/webtools`

i get a:

"WebtoolsController handler class cannot be loaded"

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was so simple!

instead of accessing `http://localhost/store/webtools`

you should run `http://localhost/store/webtools.php`